# Foundation 5 displaying small-columns instead of large-columns for high res display

Tags: html, windows, zurb-foundation, screen-resolution

I have a Yoga 2 Pro and it is at the default resolution or 3200x1800.  It has font scaling to 250. The website I'm working on uses foundation and I notice that it is not adhering on my machine to the "large-x column" styles for my page but the "small-x".  I've noticed that some sites on the web default to the mobile css.  I'm  wondering why my screen resolution doesn't indicate that the site should use the large css properties.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the zoom of the browser can affect the css media.. if you zoom in or zoom out fundation change the media screen

[fundations doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)